# Access values in xml file using python

Tags: python, xml, attributes, nodes, elementtree

```
<root>
  <body>
    <structure>
      <matrix name="abc">
        <def>
          <item name="name1" />
          <item name="name2" />
        </def>
      </matrix>
      <matrix name="def">
        <def>
          <item name="name3" />
          <item name="name4" />
        </def>
        <options>
          <option par1="okay" par2="bye" par3="hello" />
          <option par1="wrong" par2="how are you" par3="im fine" />
        </options>
      </matrix>
    </structure>
  </body>
</root>
```

I've been trying for so long to access the `<options>` node and particularly its attributes (`par1`, `par2`, `par3`).

How can I do this using Python? I've been trying `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Comment: What is the problem? Please show us your code. There must be hundreds of very similar questions here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for matrix in root.find('body').find('structure'):
    options = matrix.find('options')
    if options:
        for option in options:
            print(option.attrib['par1'])
            print(option.attrib['par2'])
            print(option.attrib['par3'])
```

You can follow paths to option and use `.attrib` to get attributes. Or, directly `find` elements using hierarchical path:

```
for options in root.find('body/structure/matrix/options'):
    for option in options:
        print(option.attrib['...'])
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to find and replace the values of the attributes?
This is what I've tried to do:
(...)
for option in options:
     option.attrib['par1'] = option.attrib['par1'].replace('okay', 'different')
If I print(option.attrib['par1']) the value does indeed change from okay to different, but I would like this change to occur in the file itself, so that when I write to the file (tree.write(filename)), I will actually see the change in the file.

Comment: @Bear Your XML data is on memory as a Python object. You definitely write it back to a file: `ET.ElementTree(root).write('filename.xml')`. Thanks for accepting!